# Hide future months in excel charts

Tags: excel

In the line chart (Excel Charts) I am trying to hide the future empty cells ( x- axis ), which don't appear until the data is entered in the source table.

[here is the screenshot of the line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmqju.png)

In the image attached I wish to show only values till Oct 2017 and hide Nov 2017 onward and when the values are entered in Nov 2017 columns it automatically appears in the chart not showing rest of the empty months

Please advise ?

Comment: Use a formula like `=if(eomonth(a1, 0)<=today, a1, na())` to create the column that is actually charted or VBA to adjust the chart ranges whenever the workbook is opened or worksheet/chartsheet is activated.

Comment: I know you said automatically but also consider manually hiding the future rows/columns and they won't appear on the chart. You can then unhide when filling out for a particular month. No code required.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the chart data a dynamic range.

Make the dynamic range, let's say you call it "Chart"
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1,0,0,MATCH(TODAY(),Sheet1!$C:$C,1),2)

*where C1 is the first date in the column of dates, and column D has the data for the Y axis*

Then in the data source of the chart, you would put =Sheet1!Chart

**Note that when using a dynamic range in a chart, you have to specify the sheet name before the named range.**